# Why does spark mllib define DoubleParam, IntParam, FloatParam, etc?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

In Spark `params.scala`, there are definitions for `DoubleParam`, `IntParam`, `FloatParam`, etc.  I want to know why the developers define those classes?

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen in the [`param.scala`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/param/params.scala) file, `Param` is a class used by Spark. There are two comments in the code explaining the need of primitive-typed params is needed to make them more Java friendly:

> ... Primitive-typed param should use the specialized versions, which are more friendly to Java users.

and:

> // specialize primitive-typed params because Java doesn't recognize scala.Double, scala.Int, ...

Hence, `Double`, `Int`, `Float`, `Long`, `Boolean` and some Array types all ahve their own, specific implementation. These use the Java classes as can be seen here (for `Array[Array[Double]]`):

```
/** Creates a param pair with a `java.util.List` of values (for Java and Python). */
  def w(value: java.util.List[java.util.List[java.lang.Double]]): ParamPair[Array[Array[Double]]] =
    w(value.asScala.map(_.asScala.map(_.asInstanceOf[Double]).toArray).toArray)
```